# Hashing - Collisions on purpose

Tags: function, hash, collision

Is there a way to design a hash such that certain subsets of the keys map to the same value (collisions) on purpose?

For example, if I wanted all (popcount>=4) subsets of some 64 bit int A to be mapped to X, and the same for B mapping to Y, etc.

I figured I could save some memory if I only had just enough keys due to collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator, and divide your 64-bit value by size of the set of hashKeys, like this:

```
hashKey = _64BitValue mod popcount
```

I don't know what language you are working with, but many modern languages use % for the modulus operator, some use "mod".

For instance, in java it would look like:

```
long hashKey = _64BitValue % popcount;
```

This will evenly distribute random 64-bit values across your keys.